# Remove ,0000 number format from multiple formula on one cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]
Hello stackoverflow i want to ask about how to remove those ,00000 (on screenshot above) im using multiple formula and "Format > Number > option" doesnt work for me

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `=ROUND()` or `=ROUNDDOWN()` function to remove the decimal.

Your AVERAGEIF formula should look like this:

```
=ROUND(AVERAGEIF($B$13:$B;"Pragmatic Play";$E$13:$E))
```

OR

```
=ROUNDDOWN(AVERAGEIF($B$13:$B;"Pragmatic Play";$E$13:$E))
```

**Example:**

[image]

### References:

- [ROUND](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093440?hl=en)
- [ROUNDDOWN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093442?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

For currency values you can also use `=DOLLAR()` (depending on spreadsheet's local setting) which allows you do determine the number of decimals:

```
=DOLLAR(AVERAGEIF($B$13:$B;"Pragmatic Play";$E$13:$E);2)&" (other things)"
```